Blender doesn't display texture what meshlab does
in meshlab

in blender

Here's obj, mtl link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bUXVT9SQKgmobXhpFkFwyDqSEbdcvtrj?usp=drive_link

hello your link asks for an authorization  ;)

You're in Solid view. What happens if you go into Material Preview or Rendered view (top-right icons in toolbar)?
